# How to implement custom authentication with jwt tokens using Serverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, serverpod

As right now I am trying to implement it but I am getting null from header for auth token. So what is the right way to implement custom authentication with jwt tokens using Serverpod.

I tried generating jwt but at serverside when I try to get the token from header I get it as null, and I am sending the authrization in header when hitting the api.